# Multiple Image Rollover with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, rollover

OK... I can't seem to get the third image to work and I know its because of my poor JS skills.  I think it's a syntax error somewhere.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?:

```
<script>
    function turnSwitchOn(img) {
        if (img.id == "fb") {
            img.src = "/images/facebook_on.png"
        }
        else if (img.id == "twitter") {
            img.src = "/images/twitter_on.png"
        }
        else if (img.id == "su") {
            img.src = "/images/su_on.png"
        };
    }
    function turnSwitchOff(img) {
        if (img.id == "fb") {
            img.src = "/images/facebook_off.png"
        }
        else if (img.id == "twitter") {
            img.src = "/images/twitter_off.png"
        }
        else if (img.id == "su") {
            img.src = "/images/su_off.png"
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<ul id="social">
            <li class="social-item">
                <a runat="server" href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                    <asp:Image ID="fb" class="social-item" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/facebook_off.png" BorderStyle="None" alt="Like Us on Facebook" title="Like Us on Facebook" onMouseOver="turnSwitchOn(this)" onMouseOut="turnSwitchOff(this)" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="social-item">
                <a runat="server" href="http://twitter.com/">
                    <asp:Image ID="twitter" class="social-item" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/twitter_off.png" BorderStyle="None" alt="Follow Us on Twitter" title="Follow Us on Twitter" onMouseOver="turnSwitchOn(this)" onMouseOut="turnSwitchOff(this)" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="social-item">
                <a runat="server" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=">
                    <asp:Image ID="su" class="social-item" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/stumble_upon_off.png" BorderStyle="None" alt="Post Us to Stumble Upon" title="Post Us to Stumble Upon" onMouseOver="turnSwitchOn(this)" onMouseOut="turnSwitchOff(this)" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: For one, the image filename in your html is 'stumble_upon_off.png' and in js it's 'su_off.png'. Is it possible the filename is simply incorrect?

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks. I've been coding for 6 straight hours and I just missed that. Thanks again. I'm going to have some food now.

Comment: Happens to everyone :)

Comment: Well if anyone needs a working multi-image rollover for HTML5 this one works great now haha!

Comment: @tonyriddle you can add that as an answer

Comment: _“Well if anyone needs a working multi-image rollover for HTML5 […]”_ – no one does. Anyone in their right mind does this stuff with CSS (Sprites) nowadays …

Comment: @CBroe, I'm sorry I am not a developer.  I am learning all this as I go along, as I am tasked with redesigning our company's website.  I see that sprites are exactly what I needed for this and I will start figuring out a way to replace it.  Sorry for my noob-ness but how else am I gonna learn?

Answer (score 0):

The image name is incorrect. In html it's 'stumble_upon_off.png' and in js it's 'su_off.png'.